# Possible to Change metadata/image/title for a SPECIFIC link/page/path BEFORE page is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, web

The Use Case:

- I have a Saas which small businesses use as a CRM. The client invite page where they can send a link to their clients which leads to a signup form.
- As of now, when you share that link with our client, it has all of
  our branding in the "link preview" (for instance, in apple messages).
- This is fine, however, we're starting to look into a more white
  labeling approach.

I thought oh great I'll use react-helmet. Then it hit me that for react-helmet to change the meta-data, the user has to be on that page. It doesn't affect the meta data in a way that the link would show the updated title/image in the link preview.

Is there any way to do this without doing separate instances per client? I'm guessing it's simple when your app has different instances like MySmallBusiness.MySaaS.com. For use, we're all one instance and one DB.

Comment: react-helmet would be a nice solution, granted that you also have server side rendering of your react app, or it will just change in the browser once the user visits, like you said. Is SSR an option for you?

Comment: Thanks @Tholle. Unfortunately SSR isn't really an option at this point. Maybe in the future but we definitely wouldn't want to go through all that right now just to change the image of a link in a text message. But maybe it's possible we could serve up this one specific route via SSR? Either way, I'd prefer to find another solution if one exists. It sounds like there aren't though.

Comment: You could just server render the meta open graph tags so sharing on Facebook works as expected etc., but still render your entire React App in the browser still.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this for link previews without sever side rendering, maybe based on path ? For eg., show a dummy graph for '/share/cook' and show recipe image for /share/recipe'